# Spark - dynamic elasticsearch query

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

There are some filter condition that to get count of subset from elasticsearch data. Since elasticsearch data size could be bigger than size of spark's memory, I decided to not load its data on spark memory but do dynamic query for each filter condition. (I thought it could be faster to get count of document with elasticsearch query than counting on spark memory). Problem is that elasticsearch query that filter the elasticsearch data need to be inside of spark rdd like below.

```
conditionCountRDD = conditionRDD( condition=> /* elasticsearch query with condition */)
```

Is this proper way to do elasticsearch query in spark rdd? if so, should I use spark session to execute each query? or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using elasticsearch-hadoop or general java/scala client? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop

Comment: thanks for reply. as I mentioned on post, I don't want to load elasticsearch data to spark memory due to size of data.

Comment: Understood, I was just thinking if you can use the data frame api instead, then it is possible to write a custom query plan that maps the spark sql counts to actual elasticsearch count queries. This is probably the most re-usable way to do this but also arguably most laborious. The base class for plans is https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/rules/Rule.scala and the rules can be set using `sparkSession.experimental.extraOptimizations`